# "Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined " when using Bootstrap Nav Active Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

Building simple website for practice and i'm trying to mark the active Nav.link in the menu give it different style so the user will know in what page he is,
I have tried to do like this : [SandBox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/718p1ovkm1)

it giving me an " Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined" error , i looked for solutions in stackoverflow and more couldn't find something that worked for me.

That the code:

The Header:

```
function Header(props) {
  const { location } = props;

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container">


        <Navbar bg="none" expand="md">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">Bloom</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-auto order-0" activeKey={location.pathname}>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link href="/contact">Item</Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link href="/about">Item</Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link href="/guide">Item</Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link href="/brands">Item</Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link href="/home" exact>
                  Item
                </Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

The app.js:

```
    const HeaderWithRouter = withRouter(Header);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderWithRouter />

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/brands" exact component={Brands} />
        <Route path="/guide" exact component={Guide} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />

        <Route
          render={function() {
            return <p>Not found</p>;
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the index.js:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The error:

[image]

The console.log of props:

[image]

Update: The newest error:
[image]

Comment: Did you use console.log on your props in the header component?

Comment: In `activeKey={location.pathname}` your location is undefined

Comment: @AlexanderElert added above the screen shot of the console.log of props

Comment: @Michael i added the console.log of props it looks like it have a location

Comment: You should use `props.location.pathname` then

Comment: @Michael same error..

Comment: Could you create a sandbox to produce the error?

Comment: @Michael This is the sandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/red-cherry-p6buo everything work there but in my vs code it's still giving me the error . and the code is the same. any ideas?

Comment: @AlexanderElert This is the sandbox :codesandbox.io/s/red-cherry-p6buo everything work there but in my vs code it's still giving me the error . and the code is the same. any ideas

Comment: @adir look at this example https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leaf-gc5xk

Comment: @Fraction still same error(added screen shot to the post).. Maybe i need to install something in my  VS code?

Comment: @Fraction It's working! i just needed to delete the Header that was in each page. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use defaultActiveKey instead of activeKey. With activeKey you need to specify the onSelect method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using @fraction code: [codesandbox.io/s/winter-leaf-gc5xk](http://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leaf-gc5xk) and deleting all the "Header" tags i had in each page of the Website solved my problem.